# "En moins que" ou "en moins par rapport à" ?

Tags: formulation, comparatifs

J'ai une question que je dois reformuler, par exemple :

*Combien Pablo a-t-il de dents de moins que son papa ?*

reformulée en :

*Je cherche le nombre de dents que Pablo a en moins que son papa.*

Pour moi, cette phrase sonne mal, mais sans que j'arrive à expliquer pourquoi. Instinctivement, j'aurai écrit :

*Je cherche le nombre de dents que Pablo a en moins par rapport à son papa.*

Quelle est la formulation correcte ?

Answer (score -1):

On dit « de moins que » plutôt que « en moins que ».

[image]

[de moins que, en moins que](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=de+moins+que%2C+en+moins+que&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3)

> **(a)** Combien Pablo a-t-il de dents de moins que son papa ?   (*correct*)
> **(b)** Je cherche le nombre de dents que Pablo a ***de*** moins que son papa.  (*correct*)
> **(c)** Je cherche le nombre de dents que Pablo a en moins par rapport à son papa. (*syntaxe incorrecte*)

La mauvaise impression que fait la seconde phrase est très probablement due à l'utilisation très peu fréquente de « en moins que ».

1. « **(a)** » signifie que le père de Pablo a un certain nombre de dents, pas nécessairement 32, et que l'on sait que son fils, lui, en a encore moins, mais on ne sait pas de combien le manque de dents du fils excède celui du père, et c'est ce nombre qui nous intéresse. C'est une phrase correcte. La plupart du temps on sait que c'est en moins, mais occasionnellement cela n'est pas nécessaire.
2. « **(b)** » n'est que l'expression de l'idée qui  se trouve dans « **(a)** » à peu de chose près, cela concernant un nombre inconnu de dents. C'est une phrase correcte.
3. 

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/moins)) 2. Dans des loc.
> a) Loc. adj. Subst./pronom./numéral + de moins (... que)/en moins. **Qui manque, qui vient en diminution**.
> • L'argent en moins et la diffamation en plus (Fourier, Nouv. monde industr., 1830, p.31).
> • Elle a dix ans de moins que sa fille (Zola, Nana, 1880, p.1426).

La quantité qui est  en moins  doit être de la même nature que la quantité totale  sous-entendue ou bien énoncée dans le contexte, et la quantification peut être précise, approximative ou relative.

- Cela fait une bouche en/de moins à nourrir. (*sous-entendu, sur le nombre de personnes dans la famille, par exemple*)
- Combien d'enfants en/de moins par famille faut-il pour stabiliser la population ? (*sous-entendu, sur le nombre actuel d'enfants par famille*)
- Il a encaissé 500 dollars hier, mais elle sait qu'il en a 100 en/de moins aujourd'hui. (*en moins sur les 500 $*)
- Elle s'est fait arracher des dents ; elle a trois dents en/de moins.
- Chaque mois, elle a 100 € en/de moins. (*sous-entendu, sur ce dont elle dispose d'habitude*).
- Chaque mois, elle a 100 € en/de moins  par rapport à son salaire de l'année dernière.

« Par rapport » ne convient pas. C'est une locution qui sert à la comparaison, et « en moins » est une locution qui sert à exprimer la soustraction à un nombre donné.

Par exemple, la phrase suivante est évidemment incorrecte, on doit reconnaitre facilement la mauvaise syntaxe.

- Je cherche la taille de Pablo par rapport à (celle de) son père.

Mais celles qui suivent ne le sont pas.

- Je voudrais me faire une idée de la taille de Pablo par rapport à celle de son père.
- Comment est la taille de Pablo par rapport à celle de son père ?

On peut répondre à la question par « La taille de Pablo est plus/moins/aussi grande (que celle de son père). », ou simplement « Pablo est plus petit », etc.

Le nombre de dents qu'il a, comparé à son père, est une inconnue, et il peut être aussi grand, plus grand, et moins grand que le nombre des dents de son père. On a donc la formulation simple suivante qui se comprend sans difficulté.

- *le nombre des dents de Pablo par rapport à son père* (= comparé à son père, ou en toutes lettres, comparé au nombre de celles de son père)

Si on parle maintenant du nombre des dents *en moins* qu'a Pablo comparé à son père, le nombre de dent dont il était question ci-dessus est modifié par « en moins », et c'est *le nombre des dents en moins* qui est une inconnue ; c'est à dire qu'on compare maintenant le nombre des dents en moins de Pablo avec le nombre des dents en moins de son père ;

- *le nombre des dents en moins qu'a Pablo  par rapport à son père* (= comparé à son père, ou en toutes lettres, comparé au nombre des dents en moins de son père)

Ce nombre peut être zéro : Pablo n'a pas plus de dents en moins que son père. Il peut aussi être plus grand : Pablo a plus de dents en moins que son père.

On pourrait donc dire la chose suivante, mais qui est différente de « **(a)** » et  « **(b)** ».

- Que peut-on dire du nombre des dents en moins qu'a Pablo par rapport à son papa ?

Comment: On peut savoir où est le problème pour ce -1, en quelques mots, si ce n'est pas trop demander ?

Answer (score -1):

> I'm looking for number of teeth that Pablo has fewer than his dad.
> Je cherche le nombre de dents que Pablo a en moins par rapport à son papa.

> Je cherche le nombre de dents que Pablo a en moins que son papa.
> I'm looking for number of teeth which Pablo has less than his dad.

Both sentences are correct.

Answer (score -1):

**En moins que** me fait remonter des souvenirs d'enfance. Les enfants disent comme des formules sans vraiment comprendre les phrases. Ce sont surtout des traductions de calcul.

Quand on dit **en moins** de façon isolée, on pense à **moins de**. `Ça fait 15€ en moins` pourrait aussi être dit comme  `Ça fait moins 15€ de votre addition`

> Je cherche le nombre de dents que Pablo a en moins que son papa.

Ceci sonne mieux dans la bouche d'un enfant pour qui **en moins** est plus un mot qu'un terme.

La meilleure façon de le dire serait :

> Je cherche le nombre de dents que Pablo a **de** moins que son papa.